# WLST JMS Bridge

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

Requirement is to monitor bridges and restart them if they are inactive.

```
connect(userid,pwd,t3 url )
serverRuntime()

cmo
```

## prints below text

```
[MBeanServerInvocationHandler]com.bea:Name=admin123,Type=ServerRuntime

ls()
```

## prints list and i can see MessagingBridgeRuntime as below

```
-rw-   MessagingBridgeRuntime                       null
```

it has null value next to it.

```
db=cmo.getMessagingBridgeRuntime()
print db
```

## prints values as "None"

How can i access existing bridges through wlst?
Is it possible to shutdown and start bridges through wlst.

Comment: I tried to edit your question but... your question is very confusing. Are you following something like https://community.oracle.com/thread/2411319? What version of weblogic? 9.2 users have reported errors